# How to correctly load saved SharedPreferences from another activity on startup?

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I thought the error I'm catching is for only the first time running (where there's still no `SharedPreferences` saved, but the error pops up everytime I run the app (in `MainActivity`):

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int com.android.test.helper.PreferencesHelper.load(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
```

The same function however works and loads the value under that `key` (`key_foo`) successfully in the `OptionsActivity` where that option is saved. `MainActivity` runs first when opening the app immediately being replaced by `OptionsActivity` after some more setup.

`MainActivity.java`:

```
public class MainActivity {
    private PreferencesHelper preferencesHelper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        
        try {
            preferencesHelper.load("key_foo");
            recreate();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            Log.d("ERROR", e.getMessage());
        }
        startOptionsActivity();
    }
}
```

`PreferencesHelper.java`:

```
public class PreferencesHelper {
    private Activity context;
    private SharedPreferences sharedPref;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

    public PreferencesHelper (Activity activity){
        context = activity;
        sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences("file", 0);
    }
    public int load(String key){
        sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences("file", 0);
        return sharedPref.getInt(key, -1);
    }
    public void save(String key, int value){
        editor = sharedPref.edit();
        editor = putInt(key, value);
        editor.apply();
    }
}
```

`OptionsActivity.java`:

```
public class OptionsActivity {
    private PreferencesHelper preferencesHelper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_options);
        
        preferencesHelper.save("key_foo", 42);
        recreate();

        try {
            preferencesHelper.load("key_foo");
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            Log.d("ERROR", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int
> com.android.test.helper.PreferencesHelper.load(java.lang.String)' on a
> null object reference

**NullPointerException** is thrown when program attempts to use an object reference that has the `null` value. You must declare **`PreferencesHelper`** in `onCreate()` section.

```
private PreferencesHelper preferencesHelper;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    preferencesHelper = new PreferencesHelper(this);
```